# How to speed up processing time for postgres query that is using index scan?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I am currently having a problem with long sql processing with my application for certain queries that uses Django and postgres. Using the built in `django.db.connections.queries` I was able to see which queries were taking the longest. I have one more complicated query that joins together 12 different tables where the majority of the processing time is being spend

Using pgAdmin I was able to use the 'Explain Analyze' tool to see where the bottleneck seems to be.
[image]

Most of the time is spent with on Index Scans matching the table ids. Particularly a large chunk of time is spent in this nested loop inner join

[image]

I want to optimize this query, but since it is already using indexes, I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Please include the specific query

Comment: Also, show the *whole* plan, and show it as formatted text, not as image. The problem seems to be elsewhere in the query execution.